# Ubuntu 18.10: I broke my laptop and it won't login at all, pls help!

Tags: boot, boot-repair

I was looking at disks with the utility and saw there was 63 gb on extended partition 2, so I figured it wasn't my main partition, partition one, so formatted it. (pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4oQ6.jpg) It said changes would take effect after restart. I usually leave the laptop on all the time, but firefox wouldn't launch from the launcher, so I restarted and it wouldn't log in - I get a purple screen, which goes black and then it hangs. I have an old 18.04 on partition 6 so logged into that and found out about boot-repair, so restarted and used the advanced options to enable networking and drop to a root prompt and instatlled it. I managed to get it to boot into a low graphics mode and ran boot repair which logged the details to ubuntu pastebin here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5cqh2ckrtm/

So I restarted and it still just went to the black screen - what am I doing wrong and what do I need to do next to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

That extended partition was a container for your Ubuntu 18.04 root partition and swap partition.
From the boot repair log it doesn't seem you formatted it, so I would try reinstalling grub. Boot into 18.04 again, open terminal and run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` followed by `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is... Don't delete partitions from your hard disk unless you're really sure what/why you're doing it.

To recover, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and install `testdisk`. Use this to try and recover the partition that you deleted. It's not easy, but it may work for you if you haven't already written data over it.

Here's some instruction on how to use `testdisk`... http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step